# How to install VMWare Workstation from dvd - but do it from the command line?

Tags: installation, command-line, vmware, dvd

I hope I haven't just missed it if this was asked before. I did some searching but there's so many posts and I didn't see anything close enough to what my problem is.

I need to install vmware workstation 8 (for linux of course) from the command line. Problem is, the software is on a dvd disk and all I've ever had to use is "sudo apt-get install..." or manually from a tar.gz. Can someone guide me how to do this?

Oh, in case you're wondering, my host is Ubuntu 12.04 server. It's a light weight install that really only has the command line, awesome window manager, and xdm. I'm trying to avoid installing gnome or any dm like that so I can stay light weight with it.

Also, here's some more information about the package I need to install. It's in a zip file to begin with. If I extract that, here's some info I get from the file's properties in nautilus (from my other computer that has nautilus).

```
Name: VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.4-744019.x86_64.bundle
Type: shell script (application/x-shellscript)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not geek but I'll tell you what I know

1. `cd /{Your DVD Direcrory Path}`
2. `chmod 755 ./VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.4-744019.x86_64.bundle`
3. `./VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.4-744019.x86_64.bundle`

And then follow the instructions of the installation. Good Luck.

Comment: omigosh! I found some stuff on the internet about people trying to install vmaware workstation on ubuntu 12.04. It look really horrible! The whole point of getting vmware for me was to not have to deal with all that. To be able to have something 'just work' for once so I can enjoy using it. Some of the stuff I saw was from a few mos ago though, so maybe they have it fixed by now. I'm just so tired of trying to fix problems and it's all I do. Does anyone know if those problems were fixed by now?

Comment: Well, that worked (mostly). I get a couple errors after installing: "Unable to start services" (and something about a log file. It's not an problem with the instructions though, it's a problem with the software of the o/s I think. Thanks for your help user1320217

Answer (score 0):

To install VMware Workstation, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

cd   /path to your dvd

***example: if your DVD drive is Ubuntu 12.04, and is mounted at /media/Ubuntu 12.04, and you VMware file is in the root of the DVD, you would do cd /media/Ubuntu 12.04***

Navigate to the folder were the VMWare Workstation installation file is located, and

```
sudo sh VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.4-744019.x86_64.bundle
```

and follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: Thanks Mitch. I'm gonna try to find out what I have to do to get it working correctly now. I hope I don't have to deal with that whole patch mess but if that's what has to be done...

Comment: Let me know if it works, or if you need more help.